# Trying to remove jquery calls to a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have lots of buttons that pass ajax around. After typing the same thing many times, I tried to create objects and pass them to a function instead. So I have the following:

```
$(function(){

    function sendBtnAjax() {

      var model = $(this).data('id');
      var data = new FormData($("#" + model + this.form_tag)[0]);

      //some ajax options then get set and sent...
    };

var uploadBtn = {
    button_name: '#upload-name-btn',
    form_tag : '-allnames',
};

$('body').on('click', uploadBtn.button_name, function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    sendBtnAjax.call(uploadBtn);
});

});
```

What am I doing wrong? Both `model` and `data` are undefined (`this.form_tag` is fine). If I pull them out and call them in the `$('body').on('click'....` part then they are defined, but when I try to pass them as arguments, they are again undefined inside `sendBtnAjax()`. Perhaps it's because I'm trying to pass a context within a context? Don't know if there is a way to do this?

Comment: What is the exact error/issue you are getting, and what is the desired behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should call `sendBtnAjax.call` with `this` as first argument, and with `uploadBtn` as second.

```
$('body').on('click', uploadBtn.button_name, function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    sendBtnAjax.call(this, uploadBtn);
});
```

Also change `sendBtnAjax` so it accepts one argument:

```
function sendBtnAjax(btn) {
  var model = $(this).data('id');
  var data = new FormData($("#" + model + btn.form_tag)[0]);
};
```

Comment: I see why you recommend that, but the OP is referencing `this.form_tag` in `sendBtnAjax()` so that function needs access to `updateBtn` too.

Comment: One might ask why `setBtnAjax()` uses `this` at all.  If it's just a regular function, then all arguments to it should probably just be regular arguments and then it can be used without `.call()`.

Comment: @jfriend00: when I tried that the context wasn't getting through. So I read that you have to use the `.call()`. Of course I might not have been getting the syntax right?

Comment: @lynvie - if you change `setBtnAjax()` so it does not use `this` at all, but rather just declare another argument to that function, then you can just call it as a normal function and pass it all the arguments it needs.  That's what you usually do with normal function definitions in Javascript.  If you want, I can post an answer that illustrates that.

Answer (score 2):

Per your request, here's an option that turns `sendBtnAjax()` into just a regular function that takes two arguments and doesn't use `this`.

```
$(function(){

    // regular local function
    function sendBtnAjax(obj, dataIn) {
         var model = $(obj).data('id');
         var data = new FormData($("#" + model + dataIn.form_tag)[0]);

         // some ajax options then get set and sent...
         // if anything was using this, then it should switch to obj
    };

    var uploadBtn = {
        button_name: '#upload-name-btn',
        form_tag : '-allnames',
    };

    $('body').on('click', uploadBtn.button_name, function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        sendBtnAjax(this, uploadBtn);
    });

});
```

Comment: Hm. I tried this and am getting `undefined` everywhere. I have a pastebin of what I'm trying exactly. I could also ask this as an alternate question on StackOverflow.  http://pastebin.com/PkvcYe9q

Comment: @lynvie -  The code in your pasteBin isn't passing a valid value for the first argument to `sendBtnAjax()`.  In my code example (and what your original question appears to want), I'm passing the DOM object that was clicked on.  In your pasteBin code, you aren't doing that any more.

Comment: Ok, if I wrap the `$('body')...` around `sendBtnAjax` this works! But to reduce my typing I'd prefer that to be part of the function. Is there any good reason not to do this?

Comment: @lynvie - you have two choices here.  You either pass the appropriate value to `sendBtnAjax()` however it is most efficient to obtain that value OR you have `sendBtnAjax()` lookup the value it needs so it can just get the value itself so it doesn't need to be passed in as an argument.  Pick one of those choices.  Which is most appropriate depends entirely upon the rest of the context of your code and whether `sendBtnAjax()` is intended to be used with several different objects.